# API with JWT trying to authenticate without OWIN

Tags: c#, jwt

I am new to all of this so please bear with me if this is a silly question. I have so far figured out how to generate a JWT and validate it (created a little program while learning). I have also learnt how to create a web API (again created a little program which queries the database and shows in postman). What I am trying to accomplish is that we want to create API so our customers can create their own site/apps. we are using JWT so how would I tell all my controllers to first go off and validate the JWT coming in the URL. It will also be base64 encoded with the claims being encrypted. However I know what I need to do with all of that as I have been playing around. My issue is how do I tell a call to one of what will be many controllers to first go off and validated the token. I have looked online and it seems that a lot use OWIn which I do not have the luxury off.

Comment: This is at least something ASP.Net based?

Comment: Hi yes sorry I am using .net

Comment: ASP.NET? .net was the obvious part.

Comment: Sorry this maybe me not understanding, but this is for a web api. in theory there would be no asp.net as this will all be done in c#. However i assume you are meaning asp.net identity. So far we have a base64 code which will get passed in the url to the api. Once there we would check to make sure if the base64 code is a valid JWT. if so carry on doing whatever the call was. it is this part i am confused about. so what difference would it make if it is asp.net?

Comment: ASP.Net delivers you with a subsystem that tells you where to add Authentication/Authorization. And there is documentation on how to do it (And Web API is also part of ASP.Net Frameworks, mostly just a specific Controller baseclass).  We(I) don't know anything about what you have. The one thing we have is that you don't want to use Owin.  Nothing we can work with. In the commmon case this can be solved with implementing a middleware, a handler (depending of the flavor of ASP.Net core is sligtly different than framwork) or just putting the right attribute at the right place in your controller

Comment: ok, so i have been looking around, possibly see if the authorization attribute might be the way to go. from my simplistic background it would be why not just create a base class that inherits the apicontroller and in the constructor have it so it unpacks the base64 code and validates the JWT coming in. All i have to then do is just derive allcontrollers from that class. However i am sure there is an easier way and probably a more cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone is interested (probably not judging by the lack of response) so attributes and using the authorization filter seems to do the trick, well while testing anyway.

Comment: Its because the question is just a long paragraph with no code or formatting. But yes, authorize is used for the bearsr tokens and the refresh token will be sent as a post request body paraneter

Comment: Hi thanks for the info Nick. Duly noted for next time I ask a question.